# What is assertion methods?

Tags: javascript, assertion, ava, test-runner

I'm learning AVAJS recently. One thing that sounds kind of abstract to me is 'assertion methods', or simply assertion.
For example:

[image]

What is it, or what it actually does in programming. I'm looking for some easy-understanding docs to read up. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most javascript test frameworks (including ava) assertion methods are simply functions that throws an error if the asserted condition is not met.

For example the method:

```
t.true(x, "x must be true");
```

will simply throw an error if the value of `x` is `1` or `"hello"` or `false` etc. As long as the value of `x` is not `true` `t.true()` will throw an error.

The way most js test frameworks work is to catch all thrown errors and output a nice report.